# How to design a school billing system database schema?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-schema

I have to build a school billing system for my client. I want to use sql server 2008 for my database.However I just can't finalize my database schema. There are so many complex issues like Advance,Scholarship,discountetc. I am thinking of creating 13 tables. 12 of which belong to month like tblJanuary,tblFebraury etc for each student and the final one for billing.Am I in the right direction??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say but I am sure that you are in the wrong direction if you have table per month per student. Looks like you are mixing data with tables (usually month is the content of a row) and would not be meeting database normal forms.

It is pretty complicated design dbs and programs. You have to thing generically, allowing your DB to store information for several years.

Check [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Anyone who can give me some ideas???

Comment: It is impossible without knowing the problem. Is it for university? For work?

Comment: And knowing the problem... it is a full job to design applications. Here you can get help for specific question, not for such general ones I am afraid.